# Creating a settings text file for python tkinter form widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am creating a form for session variables in python and (currently) store the inputs in separate text files.  How could I use a single file to hold all session variables in lists (there will be more than 2 in the final form)?  What would I need to change in my code to make this more efficient?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

regionList = open('regions.txt','r')
optionList = open('options.txt','r')
class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create Window Layout"""
        Boxfont = ('Lucida Grande', 12)

        self.label1 = Label(self, font=Boxfont, 
text="Regions").grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.regcombo = ttk.Combobox(self, font = Boxfont, width = 20, textvariable = varRegions)
        self.regcombo.bind("<Return>", self.regcombo_onEnter)
        self.regcombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.regcombo_onEnter)
        self.regcombo['values'] = regionList.readlines()
        self.regcombo.grid(row=2, column=1,sticky = W)

        self.label2 = Label(self, font=Boxfont, text="Options").grid(row=4,column=0)
        self.optcombo = ttk.Combobox(self, font = Boxfont, width = 20, textvariable = varOptions)
        self.optcombo.bind("<Return>", self.optcombo_onEnter)
        self.optcombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.optcombo_onEnter)
        self.optcombo['values'] = optionList.readlines()
        self.optcombo.grid(row=4, column=1,sticky = W)      

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("User Settings")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def regcombo_onEnter(self,event):
        varRegions.set(varRegions.get().lower())
        mytext = varRegions.get()
        vals = self.regcombo.cget('values')
        self.regcombo.select_range(0,END)
        print(mytext)
        if not vals:
            self.regcombo.configure(values = (mytext.strip,))
        elif mytext not in vals:
            with open('regions.txt','a') as f:
                f.write('\n'+ mytext)
                self.regcombo.configure(values = vals + (mytext,))
                f.close
        return 'break'

    def optcombo_onEnter(self,event):
        varOptions.set(varOptions.get().lower())
        mytext = varOptions.get()
        vals = self.optcombo.cget('values')
        self.optcombo.select_range(0,END)
        print(mytext)
        if not vals:
            self.optcombo.configure(values = (mytext.strip,))
        elif mytext not in vals:
            with open('options.txt','a') as f:
                f.write('\n'+ mytext)
                self.optcombo.configure(values = vals + (mytext,))
                f.close
        return 'break'


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
varRegions = tkinter.StringVar(root, value='')
varOptions = tkinter.StringVar(root, value='')
app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Asking for a "best" method will likely result in this question getting closed as "primarily opinion based". What method have you tried? There are many, many ways to save configuration data. Yaml, xml, pickle, and the list goes on.

Comment: There are several options when using a file to store settings. You can use a list, you can use a dictionary, you can use normal strings that can be read per line as configs for your program. I am sure there are more methods but these are just a few.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.  I would like to use a single text file with lists for each user setting.  I am unsure of how to use the lists in the combobox, or how to write back to the list if a user enters a value that isn't in the list.

Comment: Well if you are going to use a list per user then I would use a dictionary to hold the username as a key and then the value of that key would be the list of settings. This would seam like the best option IMO for what you want. Also don't import tkinter twice there is not reason to do that. Just do `import tkinter as tk` and `import tkinter.ttk as ttk`

Comment: "User settings" may be misleading.  These are actually session variables, not limited to the list.

Comment: I still think this can be done with dictionaries. You can create a session key and as the value of that key you can use a dictionary full of users/settings. There are many ways to combine dictionaries, list, tuples, strings to accomplish what you want. Maybe provide a small breakdown on the format of the sessions and user settings you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @SierraMountainTech - I appreciate your help with this.  I am unfamiliar with using dictionaries, and relatively new to python.  The variables are being used for an application I previously built that scrapes links from a website.  The variables are used to build the URLs.  Until now, I put these in a list in the code.  The variables are "Region" (city name), start date, and end date.  I may add more to further reduce the results once I figure out how.

Comment: Configparser is also a possible option.